# Python logging logs to both the files always

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create two log files and log to each file based on certain scenarios. Sometimes I want to log to both the files. I am trying out the below logic but it is logging to both the files all the time. Not sure what am I missing here.

```
  #!/usr/bin/python

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.FileHandler('one.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

app_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
app_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
app_handler = logging.FileHandler('two.log')
app_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
app_handler.setFormatter(app_formatter)
app_logger.addHandler(app_handler)

def logme(msg, both ):
    if both == 'yes':
        app_logger.info(msg)
        logger.info(msg)
    else:
        logger.info(msg)

def applog(msg):
    app_logger.info(msg)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    logme('helloworld', 'no')
```

When I run the program with 'yes' or 'no', it just logs to both the files:

```
#-> cat two.log
2016-07-12 21:00:01,630 - __main__ - INFO - helloworld
2016-07-12 21:06:26,737 - __main__ - INFO - helloworld

#-> cat one.log
2016-07-12 21:00:01,630 - __main__ - INFO - helloworld
2016-07-12 21:06:26,737 - __main__ - INFO - helloworld
```

Comment: The variables `logger` and `app_logger` are the exact same (equal to `logging.getLogger(__name__)`), so logging to one will log to the other. Also, when you say `app_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`, it is also setting the level to DEBUG for `logger` as well (again, since they point to the same object).

Comment: I tried below but this just creates both the files and logs nothing to both of them. `app_logger = logging.getLogger('blah')`

Comment: It only logs nothing if you set it to `'no'`. The reason it's not logging to the new `logger` is that you don't set a debug level. From [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel), it says "Note that the root logger is created with level WARNING". This means that by default, 'INFO' messages are not logged. So use `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)`.